# Subtarcting from total in one cell, based on data validation on another cell in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 5 columns from A1 to E1, labelled as Name, date, amount owed, status, total owed.
Column D is data validated as Paid in full, Installment, Pending. What I would like to do is when the data validation is "Paid in Full" the the amount in that row to be subtracted from the TOTAL column.
As an example if a Name LINDA is on A1 and Amount on C1 is $500 and The Data validation shows "Paid in full", and The total in E1 (Which is the sum of F1:F10), shows $1500, then I would like that amount I paid to Linda is to be subtracted from Total (1500 - 500) to show $1000.

And I would like to copy and paste this to all the columns that is relevant. I tried formulas on conditional formatting but messed up badly. Is this Possible? And I would be very appreciated for your help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you put this formula in cell E1, it should do what you need it to do.

=SUM(F1:F10)-IF(D2="Paid in Full",C2,0)

If you need to copy and paste the formula to another column, but want the formula to point to the original cells, then make sure you put "$" before the relevant cell references in the formula.

Example:
=SUM($F1:$F10)-IF($D2="Paid in Full",$C2,0)

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Hi Jonatan, Thank you for your kind info, but i am afraid it did not work, but may be i could not explain my question well enough, I could not paste the formula in other cells in the particular column, i think i will  carefully  explain the  question again after i really  think logically...but again, thank you for your  trouble. Regards.. Bulent